# Compare between FLEX, JavaFX and Silverlight

Tags: apache-flex, silverlight, javafx

Has anyone built application to compare the performances of them?

(performances like speed, different between GUI etc.)

If no, Can anyone recommend me which function (in each of them) should I use to compare them?

Thanks

Comment: Can you give us more detail on your motivation? Each come from a different technology stack... It seems odd you would be making a choice between the three.

Answer (score 4):

Try the Bubblemark animation test: http://bubblemark.com/

It runs with multiple versions of Silverlight, JavaFX, Flash/Flex, and even includes DHTML and some other frameworks.

Comment: Great link. On my machine, Flex was almost 2x as fast as Silverlight.

Comment: That benchmark doesn't really test what is usually important to test.  Here is more details:
http://www.jamesward.com/blog/2008/04/10/bursting-bubbles/
http://graphics-geek.blogspot.com/2008/04/off-bubblemark.html

Answer (score 2):

I used all three.

From my experience I can tell that Flash output (Flex produces) is fastest. Silverlight is also OK. JavaFX is again slow like applets.

The best gui is provided by Flex. But this is about taste. JavaFx also has great features about ui. But it is really slow. Noone would want to wait for it.

If you use Flex the output will be flash so nearly everyone will see it. But some may not see silverlight since they don't install the plugin or some does not have jre so they can't see the javafx.

And also there is "Open Laszlo" It is opensource and may output flash or dhtml. Does good job.

Answer (score 0):

You should try RIABench: http://www.timo-ernst.net/riabench-start/

It's much more sophisticated than Bubblemark because it's split into multiple tests and is based on true scientific methods of performance testing.